# NSURLConnection ios 5.1

Tags: iphone, ios5, nsurlconnection

So I have my connection and the methods:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

When I run my application on the iPhone simulator everything is working fine but when I run it on the iPhone, the methods are not called up.

Can somebody please explain me why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you checked your internet connection? maybe your phone is connected to an something that does not allows it to connect to internet

Comment: You're right. Don't know why I didn't think this could be the problem. Thanks